# Create php directory at root using php

Tags: php

I have this folder tree:

```
assets/
   scripts/
      sites/
        create.php
index.html
sites/
```

The create file (create.php) has the following in it:

```
<?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $fileName = $data->fileName;

  $url = './sites/'.$fileName.'/';

  mkdir('../../sites/'.$fileName);
```

I am trying to make a folder in the sites folder at the root of the website.

When I run the code above, I get this error:

```
Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /Users/mikes/websites/simple/assets/scripts/sites/create.php on line 12
```

How the heck do I make a folder inside the sites folder at the base of the site?

**UPDATE**

Through some research, I got this.

```
mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/simple/sites/'.$fileName);
```

I do not like that I have to include the '/simple/' in the url. It's not going to be very friendly when I upload this to my server. How would I automatically detect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mkdir(__DIR__.'/../../../sites/'.$fileName);
```

`__DIR__` is a magic constant, that return the absolute path of the directory of the included file. You can read more about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your're only going back 2 levels with ../../. you need to go back 3. ../../../

You may also want to make use of `realpath('../../../sites/'.$fileName);` to get an absolute URL if that helps.

Finally, you may want to check permissions of the directories that you want to mkdir in. most likely something like www-data group (for apache) and 0775 as the permission on the directory.